# How to keep last selected cell in ListView selected after clicking a button in JavaFX?

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a JavaFX that displays 2 separate ListViews like so:

[image]

There are 2 buttons to move the selected cell into the right list. Right now if I select a cell, say "Amazon Web Services" on the right and then press the "<< Keep List" button, then it will move it to the left.

However, if I want to now move the 2nd item which is "Rita M. Powell" also to the Keep List, I have to then select that cell and press the Keep List button again.

What I would like to do is to keep the top row of that ListView selected even after pressing the buttons so that I don't have to come back and select the top cell again.

At the moment how I'm doing this is in my controller is keeping an instance variable `private ListServer selected;` and assigning that variable whenever I click on a cell:

```
deleteListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            selected = newValue;
        });

        keepListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            selected = newValue;
        });
```

Then the 2 buttons are handling the moving of these cells by changing the properties attached to them:

```
    @FXML
    public void moveKeep() {
        if (selected != null) {
            selected.setKeep(true);
            wrapKeepList();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void moveDelete() {
        if (selected != null) {
            selected.setKeep(false);
            wrapDeleteList();
        }
    }
```

The rest of the controller code:

```
public class ListServerOverviewController {


    @FXML
    private JFXListView<ListServer> deleteListView;

    @FXML 
    private JFXListView<ListServer> keepListView;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton scanButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton pauseButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton moveDeleteButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton moveKeepbutton;

    private BooleanProperty isScanning = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private MainApp mainApp;

    private FilteredList<ListServer> keepList;

    private FilteredList<ListServer> deleteList;

    private AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Thread thread;

    private ListServer selected;


    public ListServerOverviewController() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        scanButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        wrapDeleteList();
        wrapKeepList();

        scanButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning.not());
        pauseButton.visibleProperty().bind(isScanning);

        deleteListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            selected = newValue;
        });

        keepListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            selected = newValue;
        });
    }

    private void wrapKeepList() {
        keepList = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getListServerList(), p -> p.getKeep());

        if (!keepList.isEmpty()) {
            keepListView.setItems(keepList);
            keepListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<ListServer>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ListServer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item,  empty);

                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getName());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void wrapDeleteList() {
        deleteList = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getListServerList(), p -> !p.getKeep());

        if (!deleteList.isEmpty()) {
            deleteListView.setItems(deleteList);

            deleteListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<ListServer>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ListServer item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item,  empty);

                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getName());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void moveKeep() {
        if (selected != null) {
            selected.setKeep(true);
            wrapKeepList();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void moveDelete() {
        if (selected != null) {
            selected.setKeep(false);
            wrapDeleteList();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleScanInbox() {
        isScanning.set(true);

        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    mainApp.handleScanInbox(paused);
                }
            };
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
        } else {
            synchronized (paused) {
                if (paused.get()) {
                    paused.set(false);
                    paused.notify();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @FXML
    public void handlePauseScanInbox() {
        paused.compareAndSet(false,  true);
        isScanning.set(false);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a listener to put the selected value in a field is not a good idea. Both listeners use the same field, so the last selection change determines the item to move, not the last change for a `ListView`. Furthermore the cost of retrieving the value is minimal and could easily be done in a event handler using the value.

Furthermore there shouldn't be a need to update the lists every time you change the `keep` property. Use the selection model to select the transferred item after moving it between the lists:

```
public static class Item {
    private final String text;
    private final BooleanProperty keep = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public Item(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    public BooleanProperty keepProperty() {
        return keep;
    }

    public boolean isKeep() {
        return keep.get();
    }

    public void setKeep(boolean value) {
        keep.set(value);
    }

}

private static void move(ListView<Item> source, ListView<Item> target) {
    Item item = source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (item != null) {
        item.setKeep(!item.isKeep());
        target.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        target.getSelectionModel().select(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ObservableList<Item> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<Item, Observable[]>() {

        @Override
        public Observable[] call(Item param) {
            return new Observable[] { param.keepProperty() };
        }

    });

    FilteredList<Item> keep = data.filtered(item -> item.isKeep());
    FilteredList<Item> remove = data.filtered(item -> !item.isKeep());

    ListView<Item> leftList = new ListView<>(keep);
    ListView<Item> rightList = new ListView<>(remove);

    Button moveLeft = new Button("<<");
    moveLeft.setOnAction(evt -> move(rightList, leftList));

    Button moveRight = new Button(">>");
    moveRight.setOnAction(evt -> move(leftList, rightList));

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        data.add(new Item(Integer.toString(i)));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(10, leftList, moveLeft, moveRight, rightList));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If there may be different items `Item` that could yield `true` when compared using `equals`, you should use `TransformationList`'s methods to find the index to select and do the selection by index instead:

```
private static void move(ListView<Item> source, ListView<Item> target) {
    FilteredList<Item> sourceList = (FilteredList<Item>) source.getItems();
    FilteredList<Item> targetList = (FilteredList<Item>) target.getItems();
    Item item = source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (item != null) {
        int index = sourceList.getSourceIndex(source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        item.setKeep(!item.isKeep());
        index = targetList.getViewIndex(index);
        target.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend rather than keeping a reference of selected item to "selected" instance variable, get the selected item on fly when you press the button. Also after doing the required operation, you call the selectFirst() method of the selectionModel to select the first option. Something like..

```
// I assume moving from delete to keep
@FXML
public void moveKeep() {
    if (deleteListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!= null) {
        deleteListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setKeep(true);
        wrapKeepList();
        wrapDeleteList();
        deleteListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }
}
```

Also you dont need to keep cell factory implementation in wrapXXX methods. you can move the cell factory setting to setMainApp() method.

Comment: awesome. got the code working as i wanted it! one quick question though - what do I put in the wrapXXX methods then? just the code to make new filtered list and setting the list view to the new filtered list?

Comment: My recommendation would be as per @fabian answer.